# trying to install SPRING SUITE TOOL(STS) but not able to extract the jar file

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, sts

I am very new to java and spring boot. I just need to understand a code in spring boot and for that I am trying to install STS.I tried downloading STS from the site https://spring.io/tools#suite-three which is for windows 64 bit, However, I am not able to extract the jar file and it is seen as below and not the actual file.

[image]

I understand the pre requisite for installing STS is java 1.8 which I did the below
[image]

I also added PATH same as CLASSPATH

still not able to extract STS.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you can run java inside a terminal, run `java -jar spring-tool-....jar`

Comment: Or just rename, and change extension from "jar" to "zip" and find necessary directory in unzipped sources.

Answer (score 0):

- Open a terminal in the same directory where jar file is present.
- run `java -jar [jarName].jar`
- this will extract jar contents in the same directory within a new folder named `sts-4.XX.X.RELEASE`
- go inside that folder and double-click SpringToolSuite4.exe to open STS IDE (Spring Tool Suite - Integrated Development Terminal).
- Start Coding! :)